# How to update gem having source as github url on heroku?

Tags: heroku

Currently we have one gem whose source repo is github and we added it as

```
gem 'xyz', :git => 'git@github.com/sandip/abc.git'
```

Now, after changing some code at github repo. How do we update the same gem on heroku ?
because heroku does not support command like -

```
heroku bundle update GEM_NAME
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to update your Gem locally in your bundle, commit and push:

```
bundle update
```

Your Gemfile.lock contains the versions of the gems to be used by the application.

```
   GIT
     remote: git://github.com/xyz/abc.git
     revision: bc9ea93f50e848f71759669918635639b9f1aaa5
```